# Expression must have class type. Don't know how to solve

Tags: c++

I'm new to the cpp language and I have a problem with my code which I don't know how to solve, I looked here on some other questions people asked about this error, but none of the answers really helped me to solve the problem.
So this is my main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Person.h"
#include <string> 


int main() {
    Person p2();
    Person p1();
    std::cout << p1.toString() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and here is my Person.h file:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H_
#define PERSON_H_
#include <string>
class Person {
private:
    int age;
    std::string name;
    int numOfKids;
public:
    Person() {
        this->age = 0;
        this->name = "bob";
        this->numOfKids = 5;
    }
    Person(int agee, std::string namee, int numof);
    ~Person();
    std::string toString();


};

#endif // PERSON_H_
```

In the main function it marks `p1.toString()` and says "expression must have class type"
and I don't know what to do, I tried many things and none of them worked.

Comment: `Person p1();` is declaring a function named `p1` that takes no parameters and returns a `Person`. The quickest solution is to get rid of the `()` or change to `{}`. This example is not quite the same as the "Most Vexing Parse", but if you search for that term you will learn more.

Comment: did you actually implement your class methods ?

Comment: To create Person object, you can just call Person p1 and Person p2. If you use (), it automatically translates to function.

Comment: Poor `"bob"` will never survive putting all 5 though college `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of statement you write can have ambigous meaning:
`Person p2();`

1. (what you want) a variable p2 with type Person and default constructed.
2. (the compiler thought) a function declaration p2 returning an object of Persion.

Remove the bracket or using the '{}' (c++11) should make things clear:

```
Person p1{};
Person p2;
```

Comment: They are not ambiguous to the compiler. It will always interpret them as function declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Various points to correct:

```
Person(int agee, std::string namee, int numof);
~Person();
std::string toString();
```

These three are only declared, not defined. This will result in unresolved external symbol error messages from the compiler.
Correct also the the variable declarations of p1 and p2.
Use this snip as an orientation:

```
#include <iostream>

class Person
{
private:
    int age;
    std::string name;
    int numOfKids;
public:
    Person()
    {
        this->age = 0;
        this->name = "bob";
        this->numOfKids = 5;
    }

    Person(int agee, std::string namee, int numof)
    {
        // ToDo
    }

    ~Person()
    {
        // ToDo
    }

    std::string toString()
    {
        // ToDo
        return "";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Person p2;
    Person p1;
    std::cout << p1.toString() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't really need `this->`.

Comment: No, not really. But it does not hurt, either.

Comment: I did define these declarations in Person.cpp file I just didn't post it here because I thought that was not necessary.